# Matrix and Vector multiplication in fsharp

Tags: matrix, vector, f#

I'm trying to make a function to calculate the product of a vector and a matrix, using F#, but i don't quite get why my function isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
  static member MatVecProduct (A : Matrix) (v : Vector) : Vector =

     let mutable b = new Vector(A.M_Rows)
     let MatrixArr = A.ToArray()
     let VecArray = v.ToArray()
     
     for i in 0..A.M_Rows do 
        for j in 0..A.N_Cols do  
            b.[i] <- MatrixArr.[i, j] * VecArray.[i]
     b
```

Comment: We'll need some clarificiation to help. First, what matrix and vector library are you using? Second, in what sense is it "not working"? Does it give you some error? Or an unexpected result?

Comment: Hi Joakim, You can add the values you are passing to function. Also, you can add the expected output and result that you are getting. If you are getting any error messages, you can add that as well which can help us in providing a better solution. You can also refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use in fsi:

```
#r "nuget: MathNet.Numerics.FSharp, 4.15.0";;

open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;;

let m = matrix [[ 1.0; 4.0; 7.0 ] ; [ 2.0; 5.0; 8.0 ] ; [ 3.0; 6.0; 9.0 ]];;

let v = vector [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ] ;;

> m * v;;
val it : Vector<float> = seq [300.0; 360.0; 420.0]
```

Comment: yeah, but we have to design our own function, so we are not allowed to use libraries that already exists:/


To clarify:
We are using a library made by our teacher with the appropriate classes to make matrices and vectors.
I can't really review my results, it just doesnt pass some tests constructed in a test file.

Comment: These are the details that you need to put in the question when you are asking a question on SO.

Comment: Of course! I'll remember that for the next time:D